# Windows Virtual Test Environments - Hyper-V based

Tags: unit-testing, testing, hyper-v

im doing automated software testing with hyper-v, tfs and so on. since our software is supposed to support every ms os since xp sp3 there is a lot of different os versions to run the tests on.

my hyper-v environment is completely setup and running fine. my question is as follows.

os like windows 7 have so many different versions (home, premium, professional, ultimate) and both 32 and 64 bit editions. does it make sense to have a vm for each version up and running the tests or would it be just fine to test against the highest edition (ultimate, 32 and 64 bit) and then assume that the test would definately also work on the eg. professional edition as well?

Comment: I'd suggest the opposite: Testing on Win7 Home (or maybe "Starter") as the "lowest" version could assume that it will work on Professional, Enterprise and Ultimate as well. One big exception (among others) will be multimedia capabilities.

Comment: Consider http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/scenarios/virtual-lab-management

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I second Filburt:
Select a reasonable testing scenario (e.g. only the least and biggest editions), but DO test all bitness-variants, at least mix you platform variants bitness in order to keep the numer of machines low, e.g.

- Win7 Home x32
- Win7 Ultimate x32
- Win7 Business Pro x64
- ...Vista & co...
- WinXP Home x32
- WinXPPro x64